# Навигация по связанным объектам django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать код:

У меня есть 6 разных кнопок на форме, и в зависимости от того, какая кнопка нажата (**button1...button6**), я выполняю одно и тоже, кроме единственного отличия - перехода на другую страницу (**page1...page6**):

**Views.py**

```
if request.POST.get('button_1') and form.is_valid():
        just_created = form.save(commit=False)
        just_created.Create_User = request.user
        just_created.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:page_1', args=(just_created.Id_Incidents,)))
```

**MyFile.HTML**

```
<form id="navigation-form" method="post">
    <button type="button" value="continue" name="button1" class="btn btn-warning">1</button>
    <button type="button" value="continue" name="button2" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
    <button type="button" value="continue" name="button3" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
    <button type="button" value="continue" name="button4" class="btn btn-secondary">4</button>
    <button type="button" value="continue" name="button5" class="btn btn-secondary">5</button>
    <button type="button" value="continue" name="button6" class="btn btn-secondary">6</button>
</form>
```

Я бы мог добиться желаемого результата, копируя этот код 6 раз подряд с единственной заменой кнопки и страницы, но как оптимизировать этот код?

Я пытаюсь реализовать переход по связанным объектам, и таких объектов у меня 6шт, поэтому, если тупо копировать код, то в каждом методе у меня будет по 6 одинаковых кусков кода, и это, я полагаю, неправильно.  Вероятно, я мыслю очень скудно, и есть правильный способ, чтобы получить желаемый результат.

Если бы я в `reverse` мог подставить массив из данных и он бы сам подставлял нужную страницу в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, это бы решило мою проблему.

**Добавлено**

В моем `request.POST` передается следующая информация, в том числе `'button1': ['continue']`:

```
request.POST =  <QueryDict: {
'Date_Time': ['2021-01-05T09:00'], 
'Id_Filial': ['3'], 
'Id_Department': ['3'], 
'Location': ['8885'], 
'Id_Category': ['1'], 
'Execution_Works': ['888'], 
'Short_Description': ['8884'], 
'Full_Description': ['888'], 

'button1': ['continue']}>
```

Comment: не помню, что там `request.POST` содержит, можете добавить в вопрос?

Comment: Dmitry, я отредактировал свой вопрос. В моем `request.POST` передается `'button1': ['continue']`.